# Centering Navbar - Vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone please help me with centering my navbar so it is vertically center on the page?

I would like the links of the navbar central to my header at the top and not floating left like it is now.

Thanks in advance

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" class=
        "navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse"
        type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span></button> <a class="navbar-brand" href=
        "#"></a>
      </div>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#header-container"><strong>HOME</strong></a>
          </li>


          <li>
            <a href="#meetthebandcontainer"><strong>MEET THE BAND</strong></a>
          </li>


          <li>
            <a href="#photocontainer"><strong>PHOTOS</strong></a>
          </li>


          <li>
            <a href="#videocontainer"><strong>VIDEOS</strong></a>
          </li>


          <li>
            <a href="#getintouchcontainer"><strong>GET IN TOUCH</strong></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the div with container class  over the div with navbar class

```
<div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="navbar-header">
```